# Jumping breakpoints - why they jump?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#

The debugger was currently set to this line...
[image]

but then

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of minor bugs in the F# breakpoint location code (even in DEBUG).  A couple of workarounds are: set the breakpoint on a different line above and step down into the code, or change the code and add "ignore()" on its own line, and put a breakpoint there.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `let x = debug` is being removed by the compiler (as `x` is not otherwise used).

This kind of thing is common in a release build where significant rearrangement of code by the optimiser happens, but depending on the compiler this can also happen in a non-optimising build.

Why not set the break point on the previous expression?

Comment: I can't get what is debug value there.

Comment: Note that the screenshot shows that this is DEBUG, not RELEASE, so there should be no optimizations.

Comment: @nCdy Sorry, I don't understand your comment, what do you mean by "debug value", where is "there".

Comment: @RamonSnir See end of second paragraph, this is  dead code removal rather than a more typical optimisation or "reorganise code to be faster".